# Axios Vue Js: How to get the value of this object to show in api get request url

Tags: axios, vue-router, laravel-vue

this is my vue file which accepts the id from table. this works I can get the data id from the table row

```
  showProd (id) {
   Products.showProd().then((response) => {
     console.log(show1prod.product_name)
   })
   .catch((error) => {
     alert(error)
   })
```

this is my config file for calling the axios.get I can reach the backend but not generating the query because this url/api sends an object I believe not the id number

```
export default {
    async showProd(id) {
        return Api.get('/products/{id}',id)
    },

    loadProds () {
        return Api.get('/products')
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like parameters mismatch. You pass "props" but use "id" in `async showProd(props)`

Comment: Sorry thats just typo of me figuring it out but still it doesn't work, also in dev tool in  network tab this is the value of the id "%7Bid%7D" instead of the number value of "id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure your API call is correct:

```js
export default {
    showProd(id) { // async not needed, axios returns promise
        return axios.get('/products/' + id)
    },

    loadProds () {
        return axios.get('/products')
    }
}
```

You can than call these functions:

```js
showProd (id) {
   Products.showProd(id).then((response) => { // Note the id in the call
     console.log(response.data.product_name) // Use the response object
   })
   .catch((error) => {
     alert(error)
   })
```

Comment: Oh my god it works man I can't believe that this " + " is all I'm missing I've been burning my eyebrows all night, thanks anyways I'll solve this question with your answer and thanks for giving time for this question you're an angel

Comment: One last question how to show this to an input?I have a tried assigning the response to property show1prod and tried  calling the data like show1prod.product_name I assume the second property is the name field in the database, what is the proper way to show this in the template? like binding this?